# How can I compare a string A1 with a value A2 (index 0's) in and array values?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to compare the following:
string A1 when selected must match string A2 when selected
if string A1 is selected and String B1 or C1 or D1, then false
If String B1 is selected it must match string B2, others A2, C2 , D2 are false

So if I have an array1 and array2 
{"A1", "B1", "C1", "D1", "E1"} {"A2", "B2", "C2", "D2", "E2"}

If I choose "A1" and "B2" from say to dropdowns, arr[0] != arr2[0] then false

I am not sure how to compare a index to an index from 2 arrays.

Thanks

Comment: So you want to check if the selected indeces are the same?

Comment: Yessir..
So If I choose A1 and A2, index 0 == index 0 //true
 If I choose B1 and B2, index 1 == index 1 //true
 So If I choose A1 and B2, index 0 != index 1 //false

Comment: And every other case is false?

Comment: Yes, The A;s need to match, the B's need to match and any mixed A to B or A to C , etc is false

Comment: You are aware that `{"A1", "B1", "C1", "D1", "E1"}` is an object, right? `["A1", "B1", "C1", "D1", "E1"]` would be an array.

Comment: Does it Make Sense?

Comment: How would you do it?

Comment: I posted an answer, can you tell me what other functionality you need?

Comment: That is awesome.. Thank you. Sorry for delay I had to run....

Comment: Glad I could help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var select1 = document.querySelector("#select1");
var select2 = document.querySelector("#select2");
var result = document.querySelector("#result");

select1.addEventListener("change", onChange);
select2.addEventListener("change", onChange);

var array1 = ["A1", "B1", "C1", "D1", "E1"];
var array2 = ["A2", "B2", "C2", "D2", "E2"];

for (var index in array1) {
  var option = document.createElement("option");
  option.textContent = array1[index];
  option.value = index;
  select1.appendChild(option);
}

for (index in array2) {
  option = document.createElement("option");
  option.textContent = array2[index];
  option.value = index;
  select2.appendChild(option);
}

function onChange() {
  result.value = select1.value === select2.value;
}

onChange();
```

```html
<select id="select1"></select>
<select id="select2"></select>
<label for="result">Result:</label>
<input type="text" name="result" id="result" readonly />
```